# proxy with HttpWebRequest in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpwebrequest

that problem in proxy , but i am want code, if proxy fail go back to start code for select new proxy from listbox without stop my program and start again, now if one proxy fail i am start again lose time , I hope you understand me.

Private Sub ThreadTask(lstProxies As IEnumerable(Of String))

```
    'iam want code to go back here if proxy fail, and select new proxy from my listbox
    For Each s As String In lstProxies

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest

        Dim datastring As String
        Dim login As String = thelogin(lstProxies)
        Dim emails As String = TextBox1.Text

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        request = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://test.com"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Proxy = New WebProxy(s, True)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar
        'here is Erorr Could not connect to remote server proxy not work
        Using postStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("id=" & login + "&email=" & emails)
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        End Using
        Using stream = New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            datastring = stream.ReadToEnd()
        End Using




        If datastring.Contains("succesfully") Then
            MessageBox.Show("found")
        ElseIf datastring.Contains("fail") Then
            MessageBox.Show("fail")
        Else
            TextBox3.Text = ("none")

        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

[HERE image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOTQ2.png)

Comment: You should share the code in the question itself. Images are not readable. What error do you get when the proxy error occurs? You should use try catch block and catch that exception and send another request with new proxy settings.

Comment: ok done im get code you can cheack that